# SQL Perfmon Trace: Wait for the Worker

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, performance

I am trying to track down a sql issue with timeouts and am by no means a DBA, but i'm stuck with the job so i'll get it done.

I've been running a trace on just about everything i can think of related to IO and network connectivity. The only number that stands out as insanely large is the one on the 'Wait for the Worker' Cumulative wait time.

Can someone explain to me what this is and at what point i should be concerned at it's value. What I have in my trace right now is 4611686018427391ms cumulative wait time. That can't be good right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That time may be fine.  It's the cumulative wait time since the instance was last started.  If it's been running for months that number would be fine.

Limit your trace to commands which take a long time to run.  You can filter based on the duration (it's in miliseconds).  Try starting with 10000 or so and see what comes up.  Start with the execution plans for these queries and see what indexes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure to check the DMV stats dashboard from Codeplex (Microsoft recomands it), it can save you a lot of time when faced with finding resource consuming queryes on your server : 
http://www.codeplex.com/sqldmvstats

Alternativley you can check out the actual Dynamic Management Views like:

select * from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
select * from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details